# App styling bar with css material ui responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hello I have a problem styling a bar app with css
of the wm material

basically i have a flex-start logo an input in the center and a flexend icon but I can't do it in my css

```
export default function MenuAppBar() {
  const logo = require('./nodejs-icon.svg');
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(true);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setAuth(event.target.checked);
  };

  const handleMenu = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (

    <AppBar position="sticky" color="default" className={classes.root}>
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
    <Toolbar>
        <Grid container spacing={24} alignItems="baseline">
          <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.flex}>
              <div className={classes.inline}>
                <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
                    <img width={20} src={logo} alt="" />
                    <span className={classes.tagline}>SpiriT</span>
                </Typography>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.productLogo}>
              <div className={classes.search}>
              <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
               </div>
              <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>
          <IconButton
                aria-label="account of current user"
                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleMenu}
                color="secondary"
              >
                <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon  style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
              </IconButton>
          </div>

          </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Toolbar>
    </Container>
  </AppBar>
  );
}
```

css:

```
const headerStyle = (muiBaseTheme => ({
  root:{
    position: 'relative',
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${muiBaseTheme.palette.grey['100']}`,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 100,
    boxShadow:
    "0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)",
    },
    inline: {
      display: 'inline'
    },
    flex: {
      display: 'flex',
      paddingTop: 20
    },
    productLogo: {
      display: 'inline-block',
      borderLeft: `1px solid ${muiBaseTheme.palette.grey['A100']}`,
      marginLeft: 32,
      paddingLeft: 24,

    },
    logo:{

    },
    search: {

      borderRadius: muiBaseTheme.shape.borderRadius,
      backgroundColor: fade(muiBaseTheme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: fade(muiBaseTheme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
      },
      marginRight: muiBaseTheme.spacing(2),
      marginLeft: 0,
      width: '100%',
      [muiBaseTheme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        marginLeft: muiBaseTheme.spacing(3),
        width: 'auto',
      },
    },
    searchIcon: {
      width: muiBaseTheme.spacing(7),
      height: '100%',
      pointerEvents: 'none',
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
}))
```

right now I'm getting this

my icon does not appear:
[image]

i want like this:

[image]

I'm a little confused how to do this with css I need it right at the beginning of my container

the search in the center

and my flex end shopping icon

Comment: where icon should appear?

Comment: the cart icon
no flex end

and the search and input on center


logo flex start

input center

flex end cart icon

Comment: I've tried it all the way and couldn't, I don't know if I should use container and grid

Comment: plz post with example picture

Comment: did you try justify:'space-between' ?

Comment: i edit picture now i try but not sucess

Comment: i want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwQWM.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203869/discussion-between-devlover-and-felipe).